# How to add the pdf-bookmark of TOC without its name "Contents" in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, bookmarks

Since the link of TOC itself in TOC looks stupid,

[image]

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}  % no `Contents` in TOC
```

is used to remove it.

However, The *Bookmark* `Contents` will disappear in the index (on the left side).

and

```
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents
```

seems solved this problem, BUT it points to the page before TOC.

So how to figure this out?

PS: `book` class is used in Texlive 2012.

Comment: Use `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` before `\pdfbookmark`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just for the sake of closure...

As Ulrike Fischer mentioned in the comments, using `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` before `\pdfbookmark` avoids the misinterpretation of the correct page.

The code should look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}  % no `Contents` in TOC

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        This is the title page
    \end{titlepage}

    \clearpage
    \pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}
    \tableofcontents

    \newpage
    \section{a sample section}
        This is the beginning of a section

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @doncherry sure, I'll edit the answer to include a MWE

Comment: Yes, it’s “community wiki”. When you start an answer or make an edit, then on the lower right you can activate this. (Older comment deleted.)

Comment: This puts all pages after the toc under a [toc-name] tab. Is there a way to keep all content before toc, the toc and content after toc on the same level?

Comment: @Me_Maikey You can change the level by putting the level number in []: \phantomsection\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{contents} works for me.