# `pdfbookmark` for table of contents points to previous page

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, bookmarks

In my thesis, I'm using the `book` class as such:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,
    bookmarksopen,
    bookmarksopenlevel=1,
    colorlinks=true,
    pagebackref
]{hyperref}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
%\input{tex/universitytitlepage.tex}
\end{titlepage}

\pdfbookmark[0]{Table of Contents}{sumario_label}\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\openright
%\include{tex/stuff}
\end{document}
```

But the "Table of contents" bookmark in the PDF points to the blank page after the titlepage instead ofthe TOC page.

Any idea on how to make it point to the start of the TOC page, not the page before it?

Answer (score 9):

This can be solved by adding `\cleardoublepage` before the `\pdfbookmark` command, like so:

```
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Table of Contents}{sumario_label}\tableofcontents
```

There is no need for `\phantomsection` in this case, AFAIK.

I could not find the exact problem I had because questions such as [Hyperref pointing is incorrect in the Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23566/hyperref-pointing-is-incorrect-in-the-table-of-contents) and [How to add the pdf-bookmark of TOC without its name "Contents" in TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97024/how-to-add-the-pdf-bookmark-of-toc-without-its-name-contents-in-toc) do not explicitly mention the problem of `\pdfbookmark` pointing to *the page before* the TOC. So I used the advice on the answers to those questions to make this one.

Comment: `\tableofcontents` issues a page break command, *after* the bookmark has been set. If the page is still empty, however, this page break command has no effect and so a `\cleardoublepage` before setting the bookmark does the job.